# Match making method to generate ballot from candidates Django

Tags: python, django, algorithm

Building a not completely standard voting app in Django (it's a bit like an online multiplayer game where people join a round on the fly to "vote" against each other), but I can't figure out how to best generate the Ballots for the use case.

I'm trying only 2 models currently: Candidate and Ballot.

models.py

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    ballot = models.ForeignKey('Ballot', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    # other fields 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link

class Ballot(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # each candidate
    cand0 = 
    cand1 = 
    cand2 = 
    
    # other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Requirement:

- Each Ballot generated has exactly 3 Candidates

Users will submit a Candidate (which is a link) via simple form:

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        field = ['link']

    def clean(self):
    #validation stuff
```

I'd like to avoid creating a pool of Candidates from which Ballots are generated and instead my thought is this approach:

For each user who submits a Candidate, it creates a Candidate object and updates a "cand" field of a Ballot object. Then, once the 3 candidate fields of a Ballot have a Candidate, the process repeats.

Questions:

- Is this a good/feasible approach?
- If so, *how* would I go about implementing it?

Any help or suggestions are very appreciated!!

Comment: The part of the Ballot model after `# each candidate` is unneeded - the Candidate's foreign key to Ballot already gives you this information. You can use `ballot.candidate_set` to get the candidates who have a foreign key to that ballot.

Comment: It seems like this is missing something important - a model to represent individual votes!

Comment: Exactly how can be voted? Can you vote for *one* candidate, or for *mutliple* candidates?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You can vote for multiple candidates.

Comment: @NickODell I hadn't thought of a model for individual votes. I was planning to (try to) keep track of the votes for each Candidate with a field in the Candidate model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (still a work in progress for saving votes etc., but this gets the basic data how I wanted it):

models.py

```
class Game(models.Model):
    this_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player1', null=True, blank=True)
    player2 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player2', null=True, blank=True)
    player3 = models.ForeignKey('Player', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='player3', null=True, blank=True)

class Player(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    art = models.URLField()
```

forms.py

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['link']

    def clean(self):
        super(UploadForm, self).clean()
        # data validation steps 
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Most of the work is done in views (I hear it should be in the model, but that's above my pay grade..)

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.POST:
        r = ()
        form = UploadForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['link'] = request.POST['link']
            link = request.POST['link']
            if not Player.objects.exists():
                p = Player.objects.create(art=link, owner=request.user)
                r = p
            elif Player.objects.exists():
                p = Player.objects.create(art=link, owner=request.user)
                r = p
            if Game.objects.exists():
                this = Game.objects.latest('this_id')
                if not this.player1:
                    this.player1 = r
                    this.save(update_fields=['player1']) 
                elif not this.player2:
                    this.player2 = r
                    this.save(update_fields=['player2']) 
                elif not this.player3:
                    this.player2 = r
                    this.save(update_fields=['player3'])   
            else:
                Game.objects.create(player1=r)
                 
        return redirect(upload) 
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    args = {'form': form,
            }
    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```